# shutdown remote machine in another domain with powershell programmatically

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a script that needs to shutdown a list of remote computers that are in another domain. And, it needs to do other tasks in between instances of shutting down a machine. I could use the runas command with shutdown.exe (because shutdown does not accept credentials), but I would have to run the runas multiple times and I would get prompted for a password every time and I only want to be prompted once at the beginning of the script so that I can go do other things while it is running.

I can save the credentials to a variable with promptforCredential, but then what command could I use that with?

The machine is in another domain; so, I can't get WinRM (PSSession/Invoke-Command) to work.
Any ideas?

This is a sample of what happens with invoke-command:

```
icm -ComputerName serverName -Credential (get-credential) -ScriptBlock {ipconfig}
```

> [serverName] Connecting to remote server serverName failed with the
> following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The
> following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using
> Kerberos authentication: There are currently no logon servers
> available to service the logon request.

```
icm -ComputerName serverName -Credential (get-credential) -ScriptBlock {ipconfig} -Authentication Negotiate
```

> [serverName] Connecting to remote server serverName failed with the
> following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The
> following error with error code 0x8009030e occurred while using
> Negotiate authentication: A specified logon session does not exist. It
> may already have been terminated.

And so on. I haven't been able to get it to work with machines in another domain.

Comment: can you please post your script so we can see where it might need improving/changing?

Comment: Well, I only have a command that will accomplish the reboots with PowerCLI (from VMware, acts on the virtual machine) which I'm trying to avoid; so, I don't have anything that will do the shutdown command. Except that I just now thought that I can play around with psexec. That can be tricky to use in Powershell though.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can use ```invoke-command``` if you pass credentials to it.

Comment: if invoke-command doesnt work...maybe you call the shutdown.exe command directly through a process object...you can pass credentials to one...avoiding the prompt

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it with start-process. It needs the equivalent of the runas /netonly option and doesn't seem to have that. Are you talking about a System.Diagnostics.Process object? How would I use that?